# angular 2 dry code http service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to fetch api from multiple sources, but don't know how to write it simple. Instead of doing:

```
getFoodData(){
return this.http.get('https://something.com/category=food')
.map(res => res.json()) 
.map(data => <Data>{value: data.value});
}
getFilmData(){
return this.http.get('https://something.com/category=film')
.map(res => res.json()) 
.map(data => <Data>{value: data.value});
}
```

And instead of repeating myself 10 times same in the component:

```
getFoodData() {
this.dataService.getFoodData()
.subscribe(data => {
 this.datas.push(data)
})
getFilmData() {
this.dataService.getFoodFilmData()
.subscribe(data => {
 this.datas.push(data)
})
```

and rendering data in the html with click of a button

```
<button (click)="getFilmData()">more Film</button>
<button (click)="getFoodData()">more Food</button>
```

What is the simmplest and best practice to do this

Comment: can anyone provide some exapmple?

Comment: For me this is a bit unclear. I see you are pushing the data in same array? Is there a difference in what order these requests are made? Should they be pushed in same array, do you want to have a button to click? Could you just explain to this stupid one how the flow of the app should be :)